# What is the best way to set up basic player movement (UE4)?

Tags: input, unreal-engine4

I am using UE4 Blueprints for this. I followed the instructions in the UE4 documentation(https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Gameplay/HowTo/CharacterMovement/Blueprints/index.html)  and a YouTube tutorial(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OExuEFp5kE0), both of which used the same basic movement setup.I copied their setups, and my character cannot look or move around at all.
 Here are some screenshots of my project:
[Movement Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okZRh.jpg), [Game Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjKdn.jpg)

I attached print strings to the "add movement input" nodes already.This confirmed that the event nodes are firing properly, and all of my inputs and keys are set up correctly. My character also can't look anywhere either. From what I've seen (the YouTube tutorial for example), characters are supposed to be able to look around by default. That did not work, and I don't know why.

Comment: Did you select the Game Mode you created in the Project Settings?,  or you can just override it in the World Settings.
Settings > World Settings > Select your gameMode AAliseGameMode.

Also, you should select in the AAliseGameMode:
Default Pawn Class > AAliseCharacter, 
so you will posses by default the character you created.

Comment: @Powelo I did set the game mode. Once I followed the UE4 documentation on animations, everything started working, though I still want to know why it wasn't working before (virtually no changes were made to the code that controls movement, and characters are supposed to be able to move without animations).